# integral- center of mass of a right angled triangle

Tags: calculus

[image]

How to find the center of mass in the $x$ direction? (answer $h/3$)

$$dm=\sigma (d-y)\,\mathrm dx$$
$$\frac{hx}{d}=y$$ 
$$\begin{eqnarray}
x_{cm}&=&\frac{2}{dh\sigma} \int x \sigma\left(d-\frac{hx}{d}\right)\,\mathrm dx\\
& =& \frac{2}{dh}\left[\frac{dx^2}{2}-\frac{hx^3}{3d}\right] \quad\mbox{(from $0$ to $h$)}\\
&=& \frac{2h}{d}\left[\frac d2 - \frac{h^2}{d3}\right]
\end{eqnarray}$$
Why it's not correct?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that

$\frac{d}{h}=\frac{d-y}{h-x}\Rightarrow d-y=\frac{d}{h}(h-x)$

$x_c=\frac{2}{\sigma hd}\frac{\sigma d}{h} \int_0^h(h-x)x\,dx =\cdots$